# Capture output of host_name() as default column value for BCP

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase, sap-ase, bcp

**Using Sybase ASE 16**

I have a table that uses a tsql function host_name() to provide a default column value:

```
CREATE TABLE exampleTable 
  ( 
     id       INT, 
     hostname VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT Host_name() 
  );
```

The table works and populates as it should.  However, I want to BCP (bulk copy) all data in this table somewhere else in order to stage it for monitoring/reporting/etc.  This will occur on many tables with a similar schema like this one.

My problem is as follows:  After bcping to a different db on a different host, the default value of host_name() changes to reflect the ***CURRENT*** host it is residing on.  Meaning, it's as if the bcp is passing the function host_name() itself, not the value it originally provided.  I want the bcp to pass the default host_name() from the source instead.

Example:  db1 has host 123.  I want to bcp over the value 123 to another db, which has host 456. Instead, the bcp passes host_name() itself which will change all values of '123' in the transferred table to 456.

Thoughts?

I'm relatively inexperienced with BCP so I'm not sure if there's a command option that retains default values.  I was also considering using `CAST(host_name(), AS varchar(32))` to replace my current default value in the table above^

Otherwise, I was thinking I alter the insert statement that populates the table.  It is currently very simple:

```
exec sp_monitorconfig 'number of open databases', exampleTable
```

This inserts the result set of a system stored proc into my table.  I'm unsure how to alter this to insert host_name() or the value it produces.

Let me know if this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: run `bcp / out / -c` and look at what's written to the data file ... the hostname (eg, `host123`) or the default (eg, `host_name()`)? by default `bcp` will apply defaults when bcp'ing into a column that has defaults and where the source  is missing data for said column ... so two questions: **a)** are you bcp'ing out the `hostname` column and **b)** has a default been defined on the target table?

Comment: It's writing the target db's hostname to the bcp file, not host_name() itself. (In my example above it would be writing 'host456')  To answer your questions, the script I have currently bcp's out based on a given table list- in this case it is bcp'ing the entire exampleTable, I haven't specified columns.  The target table has no defaults, but the schema matches the source table otherwise.

Comment: in your question you've stated the source host is `host123`, but in your comment you state the source data (ie, the `bcp` file) contains `host456` ... that doesn't make sense that bcp would be pulling `host456` from the source table; what's actually in the source table ... `host123` or `host456`? what does `select host_name()` return when executed in the ASE instance running on `host123`?

Comment: @markp-fuso My statements above didn't make sense because I forgot a key detail- the bcp is being fired as a cron job on host456- so host_name() was returning the name of the machine executing the bcp (which is host456 every time) I have replaced host_name() with asehostname() and my problem is solved.  Thank you for your guidance once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced `host_name()` in my table schema with `asehostname()` and my problem is solved.  `host_name()` was returning the name of the machine executing the bcp job every time, rather than the ASE host where the data is coming from.